# edit image using php

Tags: php

I am using php and I would like to a tool which help users cut their images using php.
When a user uploads an image it is saved (for example as image1.png). I would like to know if there is a function which allows me to do it. What have I to do for example if I want to cut image1.png which has width and height 200px and make it have 100px width?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sure is. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, possible - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

Comment: I have not tried anything. I searched for it at this forum and at google but I can not find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, use the php [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library,
be sure it's installed on your server.

see the 
[imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)
coupled with
[imagecreatetruecolor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) functions for example

Answer (score 1):

```
function setImage($image)
{

//Your Image
$this->imgSrc = $image; 

//create image from the jpeg
this->myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($this->imgSrc) or die("Error: Cannot find image!"); 

$this->cropWidth   = 100; 
$this->cropHeight  = 200; 


//getting the top left coordinate
$this->x = 0;
$this->y = 0;          
}  

function createThumb()
{

$this->thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 200); 

imagecopyresampled($this->thumb, $this->myImage, 0, 0,$this->x, $this->y, 100, 200, $this->100, $this->200); 

}  

function renderImage()
{

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($this->thumb);
imagedestroy($this->thumb); 

}  

$image = new cropImage;
$image->setImage($src);
$image->createThumb();
$image->renderImage();
```

Taken from http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1709-cropping-images-using-php.html

Edited to suit your particular needs. Visit the link for a comprehensive overview of PHP cropping.